# How to get root keys and key types using jq

Tags: json, types, key, jq

Let's take this simple data file: http://data.cdc.gov/data.json

I know how to get the root key names:

```
jq keys_unsorted[] -r data.json
```

which produces:

```
@context
@id
@type
conformsTo
describedBy
dataset
```

And I know how to get the key types:

```
jq 'map(type)' data.json
```

Which produces:

```
[
  "string",
  "string",
  "string",
  "string",
  "string",
  "array"
]
```

Is there not some way of combining this in returning pairs? (what I am really trying to do is find the key name of the first root level array, if any). I can write a routine to figure it out, but this seem inelegant.

Bonus side question: How to you determine the type of a key (e.g., I would send "dataset" to jq in some form and would get "array" in return)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jq 'first(path(.[] | select(type == "array"))[0])' < data.json
```

The top-level items `.[]` are filtered out with `select(type == "array")` which selects only items of array type; `path()` returns array representation of the path in `.`, i.e. the key names of the array items; `first()` extracts the first path.

So the result of the command is key name of the first top-level array item.

*Sample Output*

```
"dataset"
```

---

> How to you determine the type of a key (e.g., I would send "dataset" to jq in some form and would get "array" in return).

You probably mean "the type of a value", because the keys must be strings in JSON. If the path is known (e.g. `.dataset`), then the type of the object can be fetched with the `type` function:

```
jq '.dataset | type' < data.json
```

*Sample Output*

```
"array"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I wanted to get an array of all keys with array values, see I'm learning ;), would I just remove the 'first' and its brackets (sorry I don't have a data file to easily test at this second). What is the purpose of '[0]' ... does this select the first in an array?

Comment: @Narwhal, yes, without `first()`, the command returns all the keys for top-level arrays. The `[0]` selects the first (and the only, in our case) item from the array representation of path, since `path()` always returns array. For example, `jq -cM 'path(.a.b.c)' <<< '{ "a": {"b": {"c": "X"}} }'` returns `["a","b","c"]` (`<<< ...` is a Bash here string).

Answer (score 9):

The simplest approach to writing queries that depend on both key names and values is to use one of the "*_entries" family of filters.  In your case:

```
$ jq -c 'to_entries[] | [.key, (.value|type)]' data.json

["@context","string"]
["@id","string"]
["@type","string"]
["conformsTo","string"]
["describedBy","string"]
["dataset","array"]
```

If you wanted this presented in a more human-readable fashion, consider using @csv or @tsv, e.g.

```
$ jq -r 'to_entries[] | [.key, (.value|type)] | @csv' data.json
"@context","string"
"@id","string"
"@type","string"
"conformsTo","string"
"describedBy","string"
"dataset","array"
```

Or with less noise:

```
$ jq -r 'to_entries[] | "\(.key) \(.value|type)"' data.json
@context string
@id string
@type string
conformsTo string
describedBy string
dataset array
```

#### Bonus question

Here's a parametric approach to the second question. Let the file query.jq contain:

```
.[$key]|type
```

Then:

```
$ jq -r --arg key dataset -f query.jq data.json
array
```